# Solving ODE $\dot{x}=\lambda x-b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the problem $\dot{x}=\lambda x$ which can be solved via separation of variables which yields $x=x_0\exp{(\lambda t)}$ with $x_0=\exp{(C)}$ and a constant $C$. For $\dot{x}=\lambda x-b$ I have been told that the solution equals $x=\hat{x}+x^{(h)}$ with $x^{(h)}=x_0\exp{(\lambda t)}$ and $\hat{x}=b/\lambda$ however I did not understand how to determine $\hat{x}$ so the question is basically how can I obtain this particular $\hat{x}$?

Comment: You can still separate variables here. Notice that $\int \frac{1}{\lambda x -b} dx = \frac{1}{\lambda}\log \left(\lambda x - b\right)$

Comment: To obtain $\hat x$ try to find a constant solution. Substitution to ODE gives $0=\lambda\hat x-b$ $\Rightarrow$ $\hat x=b/\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda x-b$$
$$\frac{dx}{\lambda x-b}=dt$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{\lambda x-b}=\int dt$$

let $\lambda x-b=u\implies \lambda dx=du$
$$\int \frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{\lambda}=\int dt$$
$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln|u|=t+c$$
$$\ln|\lambda x-b|=\lambda t+C$$
$$x=\frac{e^{\lambda t+C}+b}{\lambda }$$
$$x=\frac{e^C}{\lambda }e^{\lambda t}+\frac{b}{\lambda }$$
setting $t=0$ in above solution, one gets $$x_0=\frac{e^C}{\lambda }+\frac{b}{\lambda }$$